# std::vector initializations and typedefs

Tags: c++11, c++14, typedef, stdvector, c++17

I know how to do this the long way so to speak:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Simple vector of ints = resized to 1k elements
    std::vector<int>  ints;
    ints.resize( 1000 );  // Easy enough

    // nested vector of ints 1k vectors each with 1k elements
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecInts;
    vecInts.resize( 1000 );
    for ( auto& a : vecInts ) {
        a.resize( 1000 );
    }
    // Again easy enough.
}
```

Now instead of typing it out like that I would like to use `typedefs`

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> Ints;
typedef std::vector<Ints> vecInts;   

int main() {
    vecInts a;

    a.resize( 1000 ); // seems okay
    // Assuming this would work...
    for ( auto& n : a ) {
        n.resize( 1000 );
    }
}
```

My question is does the 2<sup>nd</sup> code snippet do what is expected and is it equivalent to the 1<sup>st</sup> code snippet or am I missing something?

Second quick question does `1k * 1k` exceed the size limits of `std::vector`?

Comment: Yes, both source fragments are identical. Maximum count of `vector` elements is limited by `size_t` type, which is platform dependent. However one million of ints  is less than 4 megabytes of memory and will work on any modern platform.

Comment: Yes and (usually) no; for the second question, the standard probably says up to `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` bytes can be allocated in theory, and in practice, barring embedded systems, 4 or 8 megabytes of memory is nothing these days.

Comment: I appreciate the quick feed back from both of you `Ari0nhh` & `Ken Y-N`. Just wanted to verify that I was doing it correctly and not exceeding the limits of `vector`.

Comment: BTW, you can initialize the vectors when you declare them by using `vecInts a(1000, Ints(1000));`

Comment: @Ken Y-N thank you for that; I overlooked the other constructors; that'd save me a ranged-loop...

Comment: vector of vector verry often is bad design. For a matrix use a vector of size row*col. Write a wrapper with `operator()(int row, int col)` or use an existing one.

Comment: @manni66 I understand what you are saying; but I was answering another question where their `data structure` similarly followed this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two snippets do the same thing. But you can write it as a one-liner too. `vector` has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (constructor (2) on that page) that takes a count and a value from which each element will be copy constructed.

```
vecInts a(1000, Ints(1000));
```

Comment: Yeah I overlooked the 2nd constructor and didn't think about using the `typedef` as a `constructor` for the `2nd` argument; good stuff!